# recognize prestashop module issue

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have a little problem in prestashop, I can't locate and find the name of the module which allows to place on the product some text and choose it's font and the color.

I enclose the image of an example page with this module as well as link to the page itself.

[image]

[image]

http://europasaz.eu/tmp8/nappes/546-nappe-xxl-modele-ana-fond-gris-moyen-rayures-gris-clair-et-gris-anthracite-2x3m.html#.VliAuvkvfIX

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help. Mike

This is the product.tpl file

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
    <section id="center_column" class="span12">
{include file="$tpl_dir./errors.tpl"}
{if $errors|@count == 0}
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

// PrestaShop internal settings
var currencySign = '{$currencySign|html_entity_decode:2:"UTF-8"}';
var currencyRate = '{$currencyRate|floatval}';
var currencyFormat = '{$currencyFormat|intval}';
var currencyBlank = '{$currencyBlank|intval}';
var taxRate = {$tax_rate|floatval};
var jqZoomEnabled = {if $jqZoomEnabled}true{else}false{/if};

//JS Hook
var oosHookJsCodeFunctions = new Array();

// Parameters
var id_product = '{$product->id|intval}';
var productHasAttributes = {if isset($groups)}true{else}false{/if};
var quantitiesDisplayAllowed = {if $display_qties == 1}true{else}false{/if};
var quantityAvailable = {if $display_qties == 1 && $product->quantity}{$product->quantity}{else}0{/if};
var allowBuyWhenOutOfStock = {if $allow_oosp == 1}true{else}false{/if};
var availableNowValue = '{$product->available_now|escape:'quotes':'UTF-8'}';
var availableLaterValue = '{$product->available_later|escape:'quotes':'UTF-8'}';
var productPriceTaxExcluded = {$product->getPriceWithoutReduct(true)|default:'null'} - {$product->ecotax};
var reduction_percent = {if $product->specificPrice AND $product->specificPrice.reduction AND $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'percentage'}{$product->specificPrice.reduction*100}{else}0{/if};
var reduction_price = {if $product->specificPrice AND $product->specificPrice.reduction AND $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'amount'}{$product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval}{else}0{/if};
var specific_price = {if $product->specificPrice AND $product->specificPrice.price}{$product->specificPrice.price}{else}0{/if};
var product_specific_price = new Array();
{foreach from=$product->specificPrice key='key_specific_price' item='specific_price_value'}
    product_specific_price['{$key_specific_price}'] = '{$specific_price_value}';
{/foreach}
var specific_currency = {if $product->specificPrice AND $product->specificPrice.id_currency}true{else}false{/if};
var group_reduction = '{$group_reduction}';
var default_eco_tax = {$product->ecotax};
var ecotaxTax_rate = {$ecotaxTax_rate};
var currentDate = '{$smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}';
var maxQuantityToAllowDisplayOfLastQuantityMessage = {$last_qties};
var noTaxForThisProduct = {if $no_tax == 1}true{else}false{/if};
var displayPrice = {$priceDisplay};
var productReference = '{$product->reference|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}';
var productAvailableForOrder = {if (isset($restricted_country_mode) AND $restricted_country_mode) OR $PS_CATALOG_MODE}'0'{else}'{$product->available_for_order}'{/if};
var productShowPrice = '{if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}{$product->show_price}{else}0{/if}';
var productUnitPriceRatio = '{$product->unit_price_ratio}';
var idDefaultImage = {if isset($cover.id_image_only)}{$cover.id_image_only}{else}0{/if};
var stock_management = {$stock_management|intval};
{if !isset($priceDisplayPrecision)}
    {assign var='priceDisplayPrecision' value=2}
{/if}
{if !$priceDisplay || $priceDisplay == 2}
    {assign var='productPrice' value=$product->getPrice(true, $smarty.const.NULL, $priceDisplayPrecision)}
    {assign var='productPriceWithoutRedution' value=$product->getPriceWithoutReduct(false, $smarty.const.NULL)}
{elseif $priceDisplay == 1}
    {assign var='productPrice' value=$product->getPrice(false, $smarty.const.NULL, $priceDisplayPrecision)}
    {assign var='productPriceWithoutRedution' value=$product->getPriceWithoutReduct(true, $smarty.const.NULL)}
{/if}

var productPriceWithoutRedution = '{$productPriceWithoutRedution}';
var productPrice = '{$productPrice}';

// Customizable field
var img_ps_dir = '{$img_ps_dir}';
var customizationFields = new Array();
{assign var='imgIndex' value=0}
{assign var='textFieldIndex' value=0}
{foreach from=$customizationFields item='field' name='customizationFields'}
    {assign var="key" value="pictures_`$product->id`_`$field.id_customization_field`"}
    customizationFields[{$smarty.foreach.customizationFields.index|intval}] = new Array();
    customizationFields[{$smarty.foreach.customizationFields.index|intval}][0] = '{if $field.type|intval == 0}img{$imgIndex++}{else}textField{$textFieldIndex++}{/if}';
    customizationFields[{$smarty.foreach.customizationFields.index|intval}][1] = {if $field.type|intval == 0 && isset($pictures.$key) && $pictures.$key}2{else}{$field.required|intval}{/if};
{/foreach}

// Images
var img_prod_dir = '{$img_prod_dir}';
var combinationImages = new Array();

{if isset($combinationImages)}
    {foreach from=$combinationImages item='combination' key='combinationId' name='f_combinationImages'}
        combinationImages[{$combinationId}] = new Array();
        {foreach from=$combination item='image' name='f_combinationImage'}
            combinationImages[{$combinationId}][{$smarty.foreach.f_combinationImage.index}] = {$image.id_image|intval};
        {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
{/if}



 $(window).load(function() {
 $('.ajax_add_to_cart_button').removeAttr('disabled');
 $('.color_to_pick_list a[title=Noir]').click();
    var dirty_bit = document.getElementById('page_is_dirty');
if (dirty_bit.value == '1') window.location.reload();
function mark_page_dirty() {
    dirty_bit.value = '1';
}
mark_page_dirty();

    $('.newPriceHolder').text($('#our_price_display').text());
    $('#our_price_display').on('change',function(event){
    $('.newPriceHolder').text($(this).text());
    });
    //console.log($(location).attr('hash'));
    $('#image-block .new').text("{l s='Nouveau'}");
            $('#image-block .on_sale').text("{l s='ON SALE'}");
            $('#image-block .discount').text("{l s='DISCOUNT'}");

    var firstClick=0;
    $('#brodezfouta').click(function(event){
    $('#brodezfouta').hide();
    $('#annulerboderie').show();
    $('#attributes1').slideDown();
    if(firstClick==0)
    {
    $('#content-texte').slideUp();
    $('#content-logo').slideUp();
    $('.police_list').slideUp();
    }
    firstClick=1;
    });
    $('#annulerboderie').click(function(event){
    $('#annulerboderie').hide();
    $('#brodezfouta').show();
    $('#attributes1').slideUp();
    if($('#logo_monogramme').is(':checked'))
    $('#logo_monogramme').click();
    if($('#texte_monochrome').is(':checked'))
    $('#texte_monochrome').click();
    brodPrice = parseFloat(productPrice);
    $('.newPriceHolder').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €'); 
    $('#our_price_display').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €');
    $('#content-texte').slideUp();
    $('#content-logo').slideUp();
    $('.police_list').slideUp();

    }); 

    $('textarea#texte_monochrome_value').on('input',function(){
    $('#preview-text').html($('textarea#texte_monochrome_value').val() );
    if(($('textarea#texte_monochrome_value').val().trim().length ==0) )
    $('#preview-text').html('Aperçu');

    });
    if($('#preview-text') && $('#preview-text').html().trim().length==0)
    $('#preview-text').html('Aperçu');
    if(($('textarea#texte_monochrome_value').val() && $('textarea#texte_monochrome_value').val().trim().length >0) )
    $('#preview-text').html($('textarea#texte_monochrome_value').val() );
    /*document.getElementById("logo_img").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
    }*/
    $('#texte_monochrome').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#content-texte').slideDown();
        $('.police_list').slideDown();
        if($('#logo_monogramme').is(':checked'))
            {
            brodPrice = parseFloat(productPrice)+25;
            $('.newPriceHolder').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €'); 
            $('#our_price_display').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €');
            }
        else
            {
            brodPrice = parseFloat(productPrice)+10;
            $('.newPriceHolder').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €'); 
            $('#our_price_display').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €');
            }
    }
    else
    {

        $('#content-texte').slideUp();
        $('.police_list').slideUp();
        if($('#logo_monogramme').is(':checked'))
            {
            brodPrice = parseFloat(productPrice)+15;
            $('.newPriceHolder').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €'); 
            $('#our_price_display').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €');
            }
        else
            {
            brodPrice = parseFloat(productPrice);
            $('.newPriceHolder').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €'); 
            $('#our_price_display').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €');
            }
    }

    });

    $('#logo_monogramme').on('click',function(){

        if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#content-logo').slideDown();
        if($('#texte_monochrome').is(':checked'))
            {
            brodPrice = parseFloat(productPrice)+25;
            $('.newPriceHolder').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €'); 
            $('#our_price_display').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €');
            }
        else
            {
            brodPrice = parseFloat(productPrice)+15;
            $('.newPriceHolder').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €'); 
            $('#our_price_display').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €');
            }
    }
    else
    {

        $('#content-logo').slideUp();
        if($('#texte_monochrome').is(':checked'))
            {
            brodPrice = parseFloat(productPrice)+10;
            $('.newPriceHolder').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €'); 
            $('#our_price_display').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €');
            }
        else
            {
            brodPrice = parseFloat(productPrice);
            $('.newPriceHolder').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €'); 
            $('#our_price_display').text(brodPrice.toFixed(2)+' €');
            }
    }

    });
    $('#buy_block').on('submit',function(){
    error_msg='';
    if($('#logo_monogramme').is(':checked') && $('#uploadFile').val().trim().length==0)
    error_msg+='<li>Choisir votre logo</li>';
    if($('#texte_monochrome').is(':checked') &&  $('#texte_monochrome_value').val().trim().length==0)
    error_msg+='<li>Saisir votre texte</li>';
    if(error_msg)
    {
    alertMsg='<span style="color:#6666FF;">Vous avez choisi de boder votre fouta. Avant de continuer, veuillez : </span>';
    bootbox.alert(alertMsg+'<ol>'+error_msg+'</ol>');
    return false;
    }
    else
    return true;
    });

    $('#content-logo').slideUp();
    $('#content-texte').slideUp();
    $('.police_list').slideUp();

  });
</script>
<form name="ignore_me">
    <input type="text" id="page_is_dirty" name="page_is_dirty" value="0" style="display:none" />
</form>
{literal}
<style>
    .broderie6{position:absolute;left:-99999px;top:-99999px;}
    .blink_me{color: red;font-size: 13px;float:right;padding-right: 85px;padding-top: 21px;}
</style>
{/literal}
{include file="$tpl_dir./breadcrumb.tpl"}
<div id="primary_block" class="clearfix">

    {if isset($adminActionDisplay) && $adminActionDisplay}
    <div id="admin-action">
        <p>{l s='This product is not visible to your customers.'}
        <input type="hidden" id="admin-action-product-id" value="{$product->id}" />
        <input type="submit" value="{l s='Publish'}" class="exclusive" onclick="submitPublishProduct('{$base_dir}{$smarty.get.ad|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}', 0, '{$smarty.get.adtoken|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}')"/>
        <input type="submit" value="{l s='Back'}" class="exclusive" onclick="submitPublishProduct('{$base_dir}{$smarty.get.ad|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}', 1, '{$smarty.get.adtoken|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}')"/>
        </p>
        <p id="admin-action-result"></p>
        </p>
    </div>
    {/if}

    {if isset($confirmation) && $confirmation}
    <p class="confirmation">
        {$confirmation}
    </p>
    {/if}
    <div class="row">
    <!-- right infos-->
    <div id="pb-right-column" class="span6">
        <!-- product img-->
        <div id="image-block">

                            {if isset($product->on_sale) && $product->on_sale && isset($product->show_price) && $product->show_price && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}<span class="on_sale">{l s='ON SALE'}{if $product->specificPrice AND $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'percentage'}{/if}</span>
                    {elseif isset($product->specificPrice.reduction) && $product->specificPrice.reduction && isset($product->show_price) && $product->show_price && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}<span class="discount">{l s='ON SALE'}</span>
                    {elseif isset($product->new) && $product->new == 1}<span class="new">{l s='Nouveau'}</span>
                    {/if}



        {if $have_image}
            <span id="view_full_size" class="visible-desktop">

                <img style="border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
padding: 5px;
background: #fff;
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'large_default')}" {if $jqZoomEnabled}class="jqzoom" alt="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'thickbox_default')}"{else} title="{$product->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" alt="{$product->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {/if} id="bigpic"  />
                <span class="span_link">{l s=''}</span>

            </span>


                        <span id="view_full_size" class="hidden-desktop">

                <img src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'large_default')}" {if $jqZoomEnabled} alt="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'thickbox_default')}"{else} title="{$product->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" alt="{$product->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {/if} id="bigpic"  />
                <span class="span_link">{l s=''}</span>

            </span>

        {else}
            <span id="view_full_size">
                <img src="{$img_prod_dir}{$lang_iso}-default-large_default.jpg" id="bigpic" alt="" title="{$product->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" width="{$largeSize.width}" height="{$largeSize.height}" />
            </span>
        {/if}



        </div>


                {if isset($images) && count($images) > 0}
        <!-- thumbnails -->
        <div id="views_block" class="clearfix {if isset($images) && count($images) < 2}hidden{/if}">
        {if isset($images) && count($images) > 4}<span class="view_scroll_spacer"><a id="view_scroll_left" class="shidden" title="{l s='Other views'}" href="javascript:{ldelim}{rdelim}"></a></span>{/if}
        <div id="thumbs_list">
            <ul id="thumbs_list_frame">
                {if isset($images)}
                    {foreach from=$images item=image name=thumbnails}
                    {assign var=imageIds value="`$product->id`-`$image.id_image`"}
                    <li id="thumbnail_{$image.id_image}">
                        <a href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, thickbox_default)}" rel="other-views" class="thickbox {if $smarty.foreach.thumbnails.first}shown{/if}" title="{$image.legend|htmlspecialchars}">
                            <img id="thumb_{$image.id_image}" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'medium_default')}" alt="{$image.legend|htmlspecialchars}" height="{$mediumSize.height}" width="{$mediumSize.width}" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {/foreach}
                {/if}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {if isset($images) && count($images) > 4}<a id="view_scroll_right" title="{l s='Other views'}" href="javascript:{ldelim}{rdelim}"></a>{/if}
        </div>
        {/if}



        {if isset($images) && count($images) > 1}<p class="resetimg clear"><span id="wrapResetImages" style="display: none;"><img src="{$img_dir}icon/cancel_11x13.gif" alt="{l s='Cancel'}" width="11" height="13"/> <a id="resetImages" href="{$link->getProductLink($product)}" onclick="$('span#wrapResetImages').hide('slow');return (false);">{l s='Display all pictures'}</a></span></p>{/if}
        <!-- usefull links-->



                <div class="additional">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span6"> 
                        {if isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS}
                            {$HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS}
                        {/if}
                <ul id="usefull_link_block">
            {if $HOOK_EXTRA_LEFT}{$HOOK_EXTRA_LEFT}{/if}
            <li class="print"><a href="javascript:print();">{l s='Print'}</a><li>
            {if $have_image && !$jqZoomEnabled}
            {/if}
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  


    </div>

    <!-- left infos-->
    <div id="pb-left-column" class="span6">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <h1>{$product->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</h1>
                {if $product->reference}
                <h6>{l s='Reference: '}     {$product->reference|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</h6>
                {else}
                {/if}

            {if $product->manufacturer_name} <span class="manufacturername"><label for="manufacturer_name">{l s='Manufacturer :'} </label><a href="{$link->getmanufacturerLink($product->id_manufacturer, $product->link_rewrite)}">{$product->manufacturer_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a>
            </span>  
                 {/if}
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                <span class="price newPriceHolder our_price_display" style="display:none;" ></span>
                {if ($product->show_price AND !isset($restricted_country_mode)) OR isset($groups) OR $product->reference OR (isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS)}
        {if isset($product->brode) && $product->brode==1}
        <div class="span6">
                <h1 style="top: 385px;
color: #b97a57!important;
                label class="button" for="group_6_54" id="brodezfouta" style="display:block;float:right;margin-bottom:5px; "><span class="button" style="
margin-left: 15px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
display: block;
float: right;
margin-bottom: 5px;
top: 385px;
background-color: #b97a57!important;
width: 170px;
height: 16px;
text-align: center;
">Brodez votre fouta</span></label-->
                <label class="button" for="group_6_55" id="annulerboderie" style="display:none;float:right;margin-bottom:5px; margin-right:-35px;"><span style="background-color:#b97a57!important;width:151px;" class="button">Annuler la broderie</span></label>
        {/if}

        {/if}
                {$HOOK_PRODUCT_OOS}
            </div>
        </div>


        {if ($product->show_price AND !isset($restricted_country_mode)) OR isset($groups) OR $product->reference OR (isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS)}


        <form id="buy_block" style="margin-bottom:20px;" {if $PS_CATALOG_MODE AND !isset($groups) AND $product->quantity > 0}class="hidden"{/if} action="{$link->getPageLink('cart')}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="attributes1" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div class="brod-brief"><span>Délai de livraison</span><span style="color:red"> (7 jours ouvrés)</span> <br/>
    Vous pouvez personnaliser votre fouta par l’ajout d’un logo, monogramme, prénom ou message à broder  de votre choix.<br/>
Vous pouvez choisir votre couleur de fil et la police d’écriture.</br>
Si vous avez des questions, n'hésitez pas à demander</div>
<div class="broderie-container">
<div class="broderie-side-container">
<span class="header-side-broderie">
<input class="check_attrib" type="checkbox" name="texte_monochrome" value="1" id="texte_monochrome"><label for="texte_monochrome" style="cursor:pointer"><span></span>Ajoutez un texte</label><span style="color:red"> +10 €</span></span>
<div id="content-texte">
<label>Initiales / Nom / Prénom / Message à broder (max 20 car)</label>
<span class="text_monochrome_container"><textarea id="texte_monochrome_value" name="texte_monochrome_value" maxlength="20"></textarea></span>
<p id="preview-text"></p>
<label class="couleur-broderie">Couleur de la broderie :</label>
<ul class="clearfix color_to_pick_list"><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #000000;" title="Noir" onclick="changeColor('#000000');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #e67e30;" title="Abricot" onclick="changeColor('#e67e30');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #88421d;" title="Acajou" onclick="changeColor('#88421d');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #303030;" title="Anthracite" onclick="changeColor('#303030');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #cecece;" title="Gris argenté" onclick="changeColor('#cecece');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #c8ad7f;" title="Beige" onclick="changeColor('#c8ad7f');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #fefee2;" title="Blanc cassé" onclick="changeColor('#fefee2');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #77b5fe;" title="Bleu ciel" onclick="changeColor('#77b5fe');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #003366;" title="Bleu de minuit" onclick="changeColor('#003366');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #dff2ff;" title="Bleu dragée" onclick="changeColor('#dff2ff');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #6d071a;" title="Bordeaux" onclick="changeColor('#6d071a');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #de3163;" title="Cerise" onclick="changeColor('#de3163');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #e73e01;" title="Corail" onclick="changeColor('#e73e01');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #c72c48;" title="Framboise" onclick="changeColor('#c72c48');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #fd3f92;" title="Fuchsia" onclick="changeColor('#fd3f92');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #ee1010;" title="Garance" onclick="changeColor('#ee1010');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #606060;" title="Gris" onclick="changeColor('#606060');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #ffff00;" title="Jaune" onclick="changeColor('#ffff00');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #94812b;" title="Kaki" onclick="changeColor('#94812b');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #582900;" title="Marron" onclick="changeColor('#582900');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #955628;" title="Noisette" onclick="changeColor('#955628');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #ff7f00;" title="Orange" onclick="changeColor('#ff7f00');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #cfa0e9;" title="Parme" onclick="changeColor('#cfa0e9');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #bef574;" title="Pistache" onclick="changeColor('#bef574');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #fd6c9e;" title="Rose" onclick="changeColor('#fd6c9e');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #e32636;" title="Rouge" onclick="changeColor('#e32636');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #25fde9;" title="Turquoise" onclick="changeColor('#25fde9');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #b0f2b6;" title="Vert d'eau" onclick="changeColor('#b0f2b6');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #679f5a;" title="Vert " onclick="changeColor('#679f5a');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li><li> <a class="color_pick" style="background: #7f00ff;" title="Violet" onclick="changeColor('#7f00ff');colorPickerText(this);"> </a></li></ul>
</div>
</div>
<!--div class="broderie-side-container">
<span class="header-side-broderie">

<input class="check_attrib" type="checkbox" name="logo_monogramme" value="1" id="logo_monogramme"><label for="logo_monogramme" style="cursor:pointer"><span></span>Ajoutez un logo</label><span style="color:red"> +15 €</span></span>
<div id="content-logo">
<label>Logo / Monogramme <span class="gris">(monochrome)</span> : GIF, JPG, PNG</label>
<span id="upload_logo"><span>Ajoutez logo</span><input type="file" name="logo_img" id="logo_img" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" />
<input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choisissez un logo" disabled="disabled" /></span>
<label class="couleur-broderie">Couleur du logo :</label>
<ul class="clearfix color_to_pick_list">
<li><a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #000000;" title="Noir" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #e67e30;" title="Abricot" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #88421d;" title="Acajou" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #303030;" title="Anthracite" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #cecece;" title="Gris argenté" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #c8ad7f;" title="Beige" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #fefee2;" title="Blanc cassé" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #77b5fe;" title="Bleu ciel" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #003366;" title="Bleu de minuit" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #dff2ff;" title="Bleu dragée" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #6d071a;" title="Bordeaux" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #de3163;" title="Cerise" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #e73e01;" title="Corail" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #c72c48;" title="Framboise" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #fd3f92;" title="Fuchsia" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #ee1010;" title="Garance" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #606060;" title="Gris" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #ffff00;" title="Jaune" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #94812b;" title="Kaki" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #582900;" title="Marron" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #955628;" title="Noisette" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #ff7f00;" title="Orange" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #cfa0e9;" title="Parme" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #bef574;" title="Pistache" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #fd6c9e;" title="Rose" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
<li> <a class="color_pick_logo" style="background: #e32636;" title="Rouge" onclick="colorPickerLogo(this);"> </a></li>
```

Comment: It is hard to inspect, but have u tried to look something as: broderie  ? But this block CSS from product.css. Maybe it is hard coded to your controllers and tpl files? Not a module?

Comment: i think that you are right, it has to be hardcoded somewhere in controller because i disabled almost all modules and it who's still appearing. I found modules like custom product when i disabled this module it who's still there. I read every description of each module and i didn't find anything, sow it has to be hardcoded. Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: Also you coultd try to open product.tpl file and search for all hooks: hook h=''..." maybe it is a new hook? And check normal prestashop product hooks. Maybe any module hooked to these hooks. :) Also you can try to use: live edit it sometimes help me.

Comment: Thank you very much you have saved my a lot of time. The code is in product.tpl

Comment: So it was a custom hook ? Nice! Have fun with it! :D